# How to open an input accessory view through a UIAlertAction using swift?

Tags: swift, uitextview, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I have a `UIAlertController` with some `UIAlertActions` in it as shown below.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message : nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
let addMoreAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add more", style: .Default) { (action) in
    // Want to be able to call an input accessory view from here
    }
alertController.addAction(addMoreAction)
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When user clicks on the "Add more" action, it should dismiss the `UIAlertController` and open up the keyboard with a `UITextView` attached on top of the keyboard. (Like you see in chat apps like Facebook Messenger).

How do I achieve this using swift?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for `inputAccessoryView` property. You can check [this tutorial](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/03/12/customizing-the-ios-keyboard/). Using this you can make your own view that can be shown to the top of the keyboard.

Comment: My question is more on how does one even call the accessory view from a uialertaction?